# How can I sort my keys of a dictionary in python3.x?

Tags: python, python-3.x

This is my python code. I am completely new to python and would like to clarify my doubt. So kindly help me out with this. I am trying to print a sorted list of Keys of a dictionary but I am not getting my desired output.

---

```
D = { 'gible':'garchomp' , 'chimchar':'Infernape' , 'charmader':'charizard' }

print("Printing the keys\n\n")

for key in D.keys():

     print (sorted(key))
```

---

[Please find the Image of the Output for the above Code Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rHb5A.png)

The output is not what I am expecting. I want my output to be :

```
gible,chimchar,charmander.
```

Comment: Also note that you're sorting the keys themselves, not the dictionary.

Comment: dictionaries are usually used when u don't need to have the items sorted. there are ways, of course.